# MySQL UPDATE query from another table returns 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update the price of products in one table (ps_product) from another table (tmp_bmb) based on their supplier_reference.

The following query runs fine in MySQL:

SELECT * FROM ps_product, tmp_bmb WHERE tmp_bmb.supplier_reference = ps_product.supplier_reference

and returns 1700 rows.

But the corresponding (in my opinion) UPDATE query does not:

UPDATE ps_product, tmp_bmb SET ps_product.price = tmp_bmb.price
WHERE tmp_bmb.supplier_reference = ps_product.supplier_reference

returns 0 rows affected.

My tables are like these:

**ps_product**:
supplier_reference | price

In ps_product.supplier_reference the records are not unique and there are also nulls. Therefore it cannot be a primary key.

**tmp_bmb**:
supplier_reference | price  (this is the new price)

supplier reference in tmp_bmb is a primary key

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2186952/894885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you get 0 rows affected, because no data is actually changing - that is to say, the ps_product.price is already the same as the tmp_bmb.price.

To confirm this, try this for your initial query:

```
SELECT * FROM ps_product, tmp_bmb WHERE tmp_bmb.supplier_reference = ps_product.supplier_reference and ps_product.price!=tmp_bmb.price;
```

and you should get 0 rows.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew! That was the case...
When I used to return all equal data SELECT * FROM ps_product, tmp_bmb WHERE tmp_bmb.supplier_reference = ps_product.supplier_reference and ps_product.price=tmp_bmb.price; it returned all the data!