# MySQL 2 update query in sequence, the second is not waiting the end of the first one

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.5.34 (InnoDB) and the workbench.
I'm running the below queries:

```
UPDATE Product
SET
PRD_CostoEuro = ROUND(PRD_CostoEuro * 1, 5), 
PRD_UpdateDate = sysdate()  
WHERE  
PRD_FlagPC = 1;

UPDATE Product  
SET 
PRD_SpeseEuro = ROUND(PRD_CostoEuro * 0.20000, 5), 
PRD_UpdateDate = sysdate()  
WHERE  
PRD_FlagPC = 1;
```

I know that I can have 1 query, but this is an example to explain the issue I have.

I'm expecting that both queries will update the same number of rows, but the second one return 0.
If I run the 2 query one by one they update the same number of rows but if I use from workbench the option Query / Execute All doesn't work, below the log:

```
15:10:00    UPDATE Product SET PRD_CostoEuro = ROUND(PRD_CostoEuro * 1, 5),  PRD_UpdateDate = sysdate()   WHERE   PRD_FlagPC = 1    
3820 row(s) affected Rows matched: 3820  Changed: 3820  Warnings: 0 0.093 sec

15:10:01    UPDATE Product   SET  PRD_SpeseEuro = ROUND(PRD_CostoEuro * 0.20000, 5),  PRD_UpdateDate = sysdate()   WHERE   PRD_FlagPC = 1   
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 3820  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0   0.094 sec
```

Do you know what parameter I'll have to use in MySQL in order to wait the end of the first query before starting the second one?

I also tried with PHP, but I got the same, if I put a sleep(2) between the 2 queries is working but I do not like this workaround.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use transactions to get this to work.

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Transactions

Comment: done, but got the same result.

Comment: Done, LOCK TABLES Product WRITE; but i got the same result.

Comment: My only idea is to UPDATE all columns in one statement...

Comment: I know that i can do it, but i want to understand why this happen and fix my mysql installation

Answer (score 0):

do all in one stratement...

```
UPDATE Product
SET
PRD_CostoEuro = ROUND(PRD_CostoEuro * 1, 5), 
PRD_SpeseEuro = ROUND(ROUND(PRD_CostoEuro * 1, 5) * 0.20000, 5), 
PRD_UpdateDate = sysdate()  
WHERE  
PRD_FlagPC = 1;
```

Comment: I know that i can do it, but i want to understand why this happen and fix my mysql installation.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:
[MySQL UPDATE query from another table returns 0 rows affected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952365/mysql-update-query-from-another-table-returns-0-rows-affected)

Your testdata contains only 0 or NULL values in the field PRD_CostoEuro. There for your first statement only affects the field PRD_UpdateDate. In the second statement no rows are affected because PRD_UpdateDate is the same as sysdate.

Comment: first update work on PRD_CostoEuro and second update work on PRD_SpeseEuro, both are not 0 or NULL, so potentially there is something to update but in this case not so the second one will update only PRD_UpdateDate. in the second query i changed PRD_UpdateDate = sysdate() with PRD_UpdateDate = (sysdate()  + 10) and now both queries are updating the same number of rows. Seems that there is a sort of optimization, i mean if no rows are affected MYSQL do not apply the requested change. If this is true do you know how to disable it?

Comment: then the round() makes it 0...imo its not possible to deactivate this behaviour. its no optimization - there is just no value necessary to update.

Comment: the round makes the correct value different from 0, if i run the 2 queries not in sequence but waiting some seconds between the 2 runs they will update the same number of rows.

Comment: you already wrote this. if you wait between the two updates sysdate is of course different -> there for the PRD_UpdateDate field has to get the new value. if you call both queries directly sysdate is both the same.

Comment: so the update will work only if there is something to change. PRD_UpdateDate = '2013-12-06 14:00:00' if i run UPDATE Product
SET
PRD_UpdateDate = '2013-12-06 14:10:00' 
WHERE  
PRD_FlagPC = 1; the first time will update the necessary rows, the second time 0 rows. there is a way to avoid this?