# After Update Query Executed Affected rows returning 0 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to update single column in a row from MySQL table. After the `UPDATE` query is executed an `UPDATE` is happening in MySQL Table. But `$stmt->affected_rows` is returning `0`. Why is it returning zero?

```
function updateSignUp($status,$recordId){
            $prepareStmt='UPDATE <DBNAME>.<TABLENAME> SET status=? WHERE id=?;';
            $mysqli=$this->connectDB(<DBNAME>);#connectDB user written function
            if ($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($prepareStmt)){
                $stmt->bind_param('ii', $status, $recordId);
                if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                    $stmt->close();
                    $mysqli->close();
                    return $this->errormsg('FAILURE!','Staff SignUp cannot Perform at this moment.');#errormsg user written function
                }elseif($stmt->affected_rows>0){
                    $stmt->close();
                    $mysqli->close();
                    return $this->errormsg('SUCCESS!','Staff SignUp Done.',2);
                }else{
                    $stmt->close();
                    $mysqli->close();
                    return $this->errormsg('WARNING!','Staff SignUp Not Done.',4);
                }
            }else{ return $this->errormsg('PREPARE FAILED:','(' . $mysqli->errno . ') ' . $mysqli->error); }
        }

        echo updateSignUp(0,15);
```

> **Result Displayed:** WARNING! Staff SignUp Not Done.
>
> **Expecting Result:** SUCCESS! Staff SignUp Done.

Note:

- PHP Version 5.5.12
- MySQL 5.6.17
- Apache 2.4.9
- WAMPSERVER 2.5

Actual Table Looks Like:

```
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|         Field          |     Type      | Null | Key |      Default      |            Extra            |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| ldapusername           | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| email                  | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| firstname              | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastname               | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| designation            | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| username               | varchar(30)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| role                   | int(5)        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| manager                | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| currency               | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| country                | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| payee_id               | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| bank_acc_no            | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| bank_name              | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| bank_branch            | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| bank_swift_code        | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ext_no                 | int(10)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| department             | int(5)        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| marital_status         | int(5)        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| monthly_limit          | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| communication_limit    | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| medical_per_bill       | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| medical_per_annum      | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| medical_cur_year_total | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| dental_per_bill        | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| dental_per_annum       | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| dental_cur_year_total  | decimal(15,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| doj                    | date          | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| status                 | int(5)        | NO   |     | 2                 |                             |
| members_link_id        | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_on             | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| modified_by            | int(10)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| modified_on            | timestamp     | YES  |     | NULL              | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: What about executing query. Try  `}elseif($stmt->execute() && $stmt->affected_rows>0){`

Comment: @Uchiha Still Same Output

Comment: still have issue. any idea how to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all who tried to solve my issue. I was using `jQuery` `AJAX` and `bootstrapvalidator` to render `HTML form` and *submit form* using `POST`. This same issue simulated in another project and noticed that **AJAX call triggered twice for single form submit**.

Form Submit JS:

```
.on('success.form.bv', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    var $form = $("#signupapprovalform"), url = $form.attr('action'); 
    $.post(url,$form.serialize()).done(function(dte){ $("#signup-content").html(dte); });
});
```

> *To Solve issue*: I just **added** `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` next to
>   `e.preventDefault();`.

Actually no issue with PHP and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check with a `SELECT`statement if the row you want to update exists and has another value before the update than after it? Because when the value is the same before and after the update mysql will return zero affected rows. See [this similiar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186887/mysql-update-query-returns-0-rows-affected).

edit: If you want to get all rows found (not only the real changed rows) you could try the connection flag `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` (see [MYSQL Doc](http://doc.docs.sk/mysql-refman-5.5/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html)).

edit2: Okay new idea: The mistake maybe in the if/elseif/else statement that the affected rows is not read probably

Try:

```
$success = $stmt->execute();

if(!success) {
   $stmt->close();
  $mysqli->close();
  return $this->errormsg('FAILURE!','Staff SignUp cannot Perform at this moment.');#errormsg user written function   
} else {
  if($stmt->affected_rows>0) {
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    return $this->errormsg('SUCCESS!','Staff SignUp Done.',2);
  } else {
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    return $this->errormsg('WARNING!','Staff SignUp Not Done.',4);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i double check with SELECT query before Update query and after Update query. Row value changing after each query only affected_rows returning 0.

Comment: i think `rowCount()` is for PDO I'm using mysqli Prepared statement. Anyhow gettting this error `Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$rowCout in C:\wamp\www\xxxx\filename.php` after changing to `rowCount()`

Comment: Okay I hope I got it, I think the if/elseif/else makes the problem, see edit please. It's different from the comment of Uchiha.

Comment: Still No Changes. I believe there is no problem with `if else` rather when i print `$stmt->affected_rows` it return `0`. If update query able to make changes in a row then it should return some count not zero which i don't understand why :(